# Asp.net mvc 5; Where to add custom claims? (adfs login)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs

We have a mvc 5 project set up with adfs (ws-federation) authentication. Now, we want to add a custom claim to the user if a flag is true in the db. Where would be the correct place to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/26/augmenting-the-set-of-incoming-claims-with-the-openid-connect-and-oauth2-middleware-in-katana-3-x/) blog entry got us in the right direction. The claims need to be injected at the last minute after the user is validated.

Startup.Auth.cs should look something like this:

```
app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
                new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                        //NameClaimType = "User-Principal-Name",
                        //SaveSigninToken = true

                    },
                    //Inject custom claims from Database
                    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
                        {
                            OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
                            {
                                string UPN = context.Ticket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value;
                                UPN = UPN.Remove(UPN.Length - 12);

                                User user = new User();

                                //user = GetUserData("user@domain.com");
                                user = GetUserData(UPN); //Get user data from your DB 
                                context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(
                                   new Claim("UserName", user.UserName.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String, "LOCAL AUTHORITY"));

                            }
                        }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set up a SQL attribute [store](http://lucvknet.blogspot.co.nz/2009/12/using-sql-attribute-store-with-active.html) and then write a custom rule to [query](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4792.understanding-claim-rule-language-in-ad-fs-2-0-higher.aspx) the store.

As per the article, something like:

```
c:[type == "http://contoso.com/emailaddress"]
=> issue (store = "Custom SQL Store", types = ("http://contoso.com/age", "http://contoso.com/purchasinglimit"), query = "SELECT age,purchasinglimit FROM users WHERE email={0}",param = c.value);
```